Passing affine transform to rasterio.features.rasterize()
I have generated a raster using code like the following:
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = l1.bounds
dx = (maxx - minx)
dy = (maxy - miny)

buildings_raster = rasterio.features.rasterize([l1],
                   out_shape=(math.ceil(dy)+2, math.ceil(dx)+2),
                   transform=(1.0,0,minx, 0,1.0,miny, 1,1,0), all_touched=False)

Looking at the raster data it makes sense.
I wanted to use rasterio.transform.rowcol() to convert xy points to rowcol indices to extract values from the created raster, but it did not like it when I tried:
rows, cols = rasterio.transform.rowcol([1.0,0,minx, 0,1.0,miny, 1,1,0], xs, ys)

I'm guessing passing a tuple is not the right way to pass the transform to rowcol().
What is the right way to pass the transform to rowcol()?
I tried:
transform = rasterio.Affine(1.0,0,minx, 0,1.0,miny, 1,1,0)
rows, cols = rasterio.transform.rowcol(transform, xs, ys)

but it doesn't like that either.
Edit: Re: "doesn't like that either", Python was reporting the error:
ValueError: GCPTransformer requires sequence of GroundControlPoint

That was leading me to believe it wanted bounds min/max values or the affine components in a list or tuple.  But it turns out it wants a rasterio.Affine object, like this.
transform = rasterio.Affine(1.0, 0.0, minx, 0.0, 1.0, miny)
rows, cols = rasterio.transform.rowcol(transform, xs, ys)


I updated the question, with the error message I was getting, and with the solution.
